# Which CSS property is responsible for the difference in appearance between two elements with identical CSS settings?

Tags: css, debugging

The HTML below specifies a `button` and a `div` that have identical class and contents.

```
<div class="root"><!--
--><button class="outer"><div class="middle"><div class="inner">label</div></div></button><!--
--><div    class="outer"><div class="middle"><div class="inner">label</div></div></div   ><!--
--></div>
```

In this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/1w60mott/), I have ***explicitly set every CSS property***<sup>1</sup> for the classes `outer`, `middle`, and `inner`<sup>2</sup>.

This means that both the `button.outer` and `div.outer` sub-trees of the DOM should have *completely identical CSS settings*.  Presumably, as well, no CSS properties for these elements are getting their values from anywhere else besides the provided stylesheet.

As the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/1w60mott/) shows, the side-by-side `button` and `div` look quite different.  Specifically, in the `button`, the label appears at the bottom of the element, whereas in the `div` it is vertically centered.  (The label is centered horizontally in both cases.  Also, note that all the classes have the setting `vertical-align: middle`.)

I have observed this difference with all the browsers I've tested so far (Chrome and Firefox).

Since there is no difference in the stylesheet settings for the `button.outer` and `div.outer` elements, and their descendants, I figure that the difference in their appearance is due to some CSS property with a value (such as `auto` or `normal`) that gets interpreted differently by the browser depending on the whether the context is a `button` or a `div` element.

**My immediate goal here is to *understand* sufficiently well why the `button` and the `div` are being rendered differently so that I can adjust the CSS intelligently.**

My longer term goal is to make CSS coding more predictable.  Currently I find that my CSS is *completely unstable* due to gross inconsistencies like the one shown in the example.

My question is:

> how can the difference in appearance between the `button` and the `div` be explained?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> As reported by Chrome's devtool.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> I took the vast majority of the values for these settings from Chrome's devtool's listings.  The point was to ensure that both the `button` and the `div` elements had the same setting (whatever it may be) for each CSS property.</sup>

Comment: From what I could tell, it's the `position: absolute` on your `.middle` selector.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach: thanks for your comment.  After reading it I had to rephrase my question.  I know that the `position: absolute` contributes to the situation, but that still does not tell me enough fix the problem.  I'm hoping that by tweaking some other of the CSS properties (namely those with value `auto`, `normal`, etc.) I will be able to make the `button` look more like the `div`.  Getting rid of `.middle`'s `position: absolute` is definitely not an option in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to different meanings for the value of `auto` for the position of elements inside of a `button`. If you expand the size of a `div`, the content by default will be in the top-left corner. If you do the same for a button, the content will be centered horizontally and vertically.

Since the button's `top` and `left` values for `auto` is to be centered and not in the top left corner, you can reset top and left to always act like a typical div would. These are the properties to change on `.middle`:

```
.middle {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Here's the [forked JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0sr4a2r/) with those changes to `.middle`.

Comment: Marc, I wish I could give you 1000+'s!  Just the fact that you got the point of my question (let alone found an answer) is already great.

Comment: BTW, it turns out that, in this case at least, it's enough to set `top: 0`.

Comment: @kjo That's interesting, I'm guessing the absolute positioning resets the left's auto, but not the top. It's definitely not a bug, or at least it's one every browser is doing consistently.

Comment: I agree, it's weird.  I just figured that if the `left` had also been a problem, then the text would have been shoved in the bottom right corner (because the top-left corner would have been placed in the center, both vertically and horizontally).  Thanks again!  I would have not seen the solution to this one in a million years.

Answer (score 1):

Different elements have different default settings. There is an *enormous* amount of CSS in your demos, and it's largely overkill and very hard to determine where exactly the differences in rendering are coming from.

Have you tried a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/) instead? These will resolve most of the discrepancies between elements and browsers, giving you a blank slate to add your own styles.

Comment: @Ben: it should not matter.  My CSS is explicitly setting *everything*.  Shouldn't this override all the other stylesheets?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I determine the property (or properties) that account for the difference in appearance between the button and the div?

By clicking through them one by one and toggling them on and off in Dev Tools. If you turn off `position:absolute` on the `middle` class, you'll see what you're probably expecting in layout. I found this by clicking through all the properties in the Elements > Styles panel. See:

https://jsfiddle.net/vfdd9p8L/

This is probably a bug that you're encountering. Browsers have lots of them! By layering on so many styles at once, you're probably backing into a weird corner case with respect to the layout algorithms. To isolate the bug for help and/or reporting, try to create a reduced test case, which creates an unexpected discrepancy, but using the minimal number of elements and declarations.

(Also note that your fiddle is including jQuery CSS, which includes Normalize, which is a whole other layer of styling.)

Comment: It's "damned if you, damned if you don't".  If I did not set all the properties, then the difference in appearance between the `button` and the `div` gets chalked to some default setting by the browser, etc.  But if I set all the properties to rule out this possibility, then the discrepancy gets chalked to some weird interaction among all the settings...  This is truly exhausting...  BTW, the fact that I've **set everything** means that any other stylesheets floating (normalize.css, jquery css, whatever) around should be irrelevant.

Comment: Welcome to layout. Believe it or not it's much better than it used to be. Your issue is not a UA default setting, or you would see it in dev tools. Try to get over that idea. It might be in a perfect world, but that's not where we live. It is *definitely* "a weird interaction among all the settings". Position absolute, top "auto" in a button does something different from in a div. File a bug! This is why CSS is a fulltime job. You can insulting call it "la-la land" in your question, and still get free help, but then if it's so easy to do why are you running to Stack Overflow? You're welcome!

Comment: My reference to "CSS-la-la-land" was another way of stating that, with CSS, it is anyone's guess what the various directives will do in the end.  Not very different from your comment about "weird interactions".  But, since it seems like it was liable to be misinterpreted, I deleted it.