# What CSS settings account for differences between buttons and divs in child's vertical positioning?

Tags: css, debugging

**Code snippet ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wooLv4ao/)):**

```css
.root * {
    cursor: default;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;

    padding: 0px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;

    text-align: center;

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.clickable {
    background: orange;
    margin: 5px;

    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}

.clickable .label {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root" style="padding: 60px;"><!--
 --><button class="clickable"><span class="label">label</span></button><!--
 --><div    class="clickable"><span class="label">label</span></div   ><!--
 --></div>
```

Even though the CSS directives for the `button` (on the left) and the `div`, and for their contents, are identical, the vertical positioning of these contents is completely different:
[image]
I would like to know

> what other CSS setting accounts for this difference?

(Note: by "other CSS setting" I mean one that is not explicitly set in the example's CSS.)

---

**EDIT:**

I've created another [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65edqjrm/) to demonstrate why @Jim's suggestion (in his comment) does not always work.  In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65edqjrm/), *all the CSS properties (including the inherited/computed/browser-assigned/you-name-it ones)* for the `.clickable` and `.clickable .label` classes *are given explicit values*.

Even though these settings make no explicit distinction between buttons and divs, the observed difference in vertical positioning between buttons and divs persists.

**This means that the explanation has to be that some setting (probably one that has value like `auto` or `normal`) is getting interpreted differently depending on whether the context is a button or a div.**  Such context-dependence contributes much to making CSS the living hell that it is.

Comment: The best way to troubleshoot this is to use the Developer Tools available in IE / Chrome / Firefox / whatever, and see what exact CSS is being applied to each element.  Sometimes if you're not using a reset.css, some browsers will apply user agent CSS (i.e. browser defaults), and those settings can be different for each type of element.  With most Developer Tools, you can edit the CSS and play around with disabling certain CSS until you figure out what your culprit is.

Comment: @Jim: I've created another [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65edqjrm/) to demonstrate why your suggestion does not always work.  In particular, it does not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's your `line-height: 0px;` value that is affecting the div. On block level elements, the `line-height` properties specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element. Elements such as buttons or other input elements, `line-height` has no effect.

**Update**

I should say that in some cases `line-height` is allowed to have affects on buttons.

Comment: If you go to his JSFiddle though and remove the line-height, it does make the text in the DIV move down a bit, but it still isn't middle aligned like the button, it is top aligned.  I'm sure what you've said is probably true, but that doesn't look to be the sole cause of the discrepancy between the styling of the two elements.

Comment: Adjust the line-height value and they will match. Here's the revised fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/wooLv4ao/1/, notice how the line height affects the button only after a certain value (i.e., `> 40px`). It's why I said in some cases.

Comment: @ChrisYongchu: Thanks, but this does not answer my question.  I did not ask for how to change the existing CSS so that the button and the div match.  I asked "what ***other*** setting accounts for this difference?"  If a setting is the same for both button and div, it can't, by itself, account for the difference between button and div.

Comment: @kjo. Well, `<a>`, `<div>`s and `<span>`s are not buttons. Therefore they won't behave the same way. TL;DR https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Comment: @kjo, I've put together a very vanilla fiddle together for you to examine and review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/rvdb4881/

Comment: Thanks for the link and the jsFiddle.  I had hoped (but maybe this is unrealistic) that the differences in behavior between divs and buttons would ultimately boil down to the values of specific properties.  E.g. for some hypothetical property `foo`, a setting of `foo: auto` for buttons would be the same as `foo: 50%`, but for divs `foo: auto` would be the same as `foo: 0`.  If so, `foo: auto` would have different effects on buttons and divs (as in my question).  If so, at least one could explicitly set, for example, `foo: 0` on both buttons and divs, and thus override the default...

Comment: ...difference in the handling of buttons and divs.  Something very much like this turned out to be the answer to an [earlier question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32217678/559827).  The observed differences could be traced to different interpretations, depending on the context, of the same CSS setting, `top: auto`.  Once this was identified, the solution was trivial: simply setting `top` to an unambiguous value (e.g. `top: 0`) eliminated the context-dependent differences in behavior.  I was hoping to find a similar critical setting for the case in this question.